# C++ writing sectors to a CD

Tags: c++, disk

I've written a filesystem simulation code in C++ that creates a binary file in disk (using fstream). I have written methods that write in blocks of size 512 bytes (like a sector on disk).

Now I want to convert that code so that in can operate on real CD-RW. How can I read/write sectors on that disk using C++?  I need to able to control read/write on each sector and track and surface of disk.

OS is Linux.

Let me know if I'm not clear :)

Comment: That depends on operating system.

Comment: That's not how CD-RW's work.

Comment: can i write in any way sector by sector to an external disk?

Comment: Whatever OS you are using, it requires you to go through and implement some part of [ECMA-130](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-130.htm) standard.